# Coded UI - How to make each remote system with a test agent run all the Test Scripts in parallel

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a set of Test Scripts which I need to test on a few different operating systems. I have connected the remote machines with these OS using Test agents to my local machine. I will run through Visual Studio by adding a test settings file.

Doing this, it distributes the Test Scripts set among the remote machine, but I want each of the remote machine to run each of the test. i.e. each script must execute on every remote system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test mix of the scenario set the tests to run in [Sequential order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514186%28v=vs.120%29.aspx#SequentialOrder). This will make each virtual user run all of the tests.